# Laravel validation: Required only and only one field

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have got two fields namely number and percentage. I want a user to input value in only one input field. If a user inputs values in both number and percentage field, the system should throw validation error. Is there anything we can do with laravel validation to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can write a custom validator for that:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

It may looks somthing like this:

```
class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

    public function validateEmpty($attribute, $value)
    {
        return ! $this->validateRequired($attribute, $value);
    }

    public function validateEmptyIf($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $key = $parameters[0];

        if ($this->validateRequired($key, $this->getValue($key))) {
            return $this->validateEmpty($attribute, $value);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Register it in a service provider:

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $attributes)
{
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $attributes);
});
```

Use it (in a form request, for example):

```
class StoreSomethingRequest extends FormRequest {
    // ...

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'percentage' => 'empty_if:number',
            'number'     => 'empty_if:percentage',
        ];
    }
}
```

**Update**
Just tested it in Tinker:

```
Validator::make(['foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 'bar'], ['bar' => 'empty_if:foo'])->fails()
=> true
Validator::make(['foo' => '', 'bar' => 'bar'], ['bar' => 'empty_if:foo'])->fails()
=> false
Validator::make(['foo' => '', 'bar' => 'bar'], ['foo' => 'empty_if:bar'])->fails()
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be a good solution as well:

```
return [
    'video' => [
        'bail',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (request()->has($attribute) === request()->filled('videourl')) {
                return $fail('Only 1 of the two is allowed');
            }
        },
        'file',
    ],
   'videourl' => [
        'bail',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (request()->has($attribute) === request()->filled('video')) {
                return $fail('Only 1 of the two is allowed');
            }
        },
    ]
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried anonymous functions and I didn't want to create a new custom rule for such a small functionality. This helped me