# Laravel 5.2 Validation required_without fails on more than 2 fields

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a form with checkboxes and text inputs.

In each group of checkboxes I want a validation that, at least, one checkbox must be checked. I did my validation rules like this:

```
$validRules = [
    "check1" => "required_without:check2,check3,check4,check5",
    "check2" => "required_without:check1,check3,check4,check5",
    "check3" => "required_without:check2,check1,check4,check5",
    "check4" => "required_without:check2,check3,check1,check5",
    "check5" => "required_without:check2,check3,check4,check1",
    //more rules...
];
```

What I need to achieve is to get an error ONLY if there is no checkbox checked, but no error if one, two or more are checked.

When I submit the form, the validation throws a validation error if they are not all checked. Are my rules wrong or this is a bug?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Try this [same type of question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635678/laravel-validation-required-only-and-only-one-field)

Answer (score 2):

Change required_without to required_without_all:

```
$validRules = [
    "check1" => "required_without_all:check2,check3,check4,check5",
    // the rest of your rules
];
```

Alternatively if you used an array for your checkbox names e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2">
```

You can just require one of them by using:

```
$validRules = [
    'checkbox' => 'required'
];
```

Comment: Reading the docs I have understood that `required_without_all` is for throwing an error when one of them is unchecked, Am I wrong?

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal required_without_all means it's only required if all the other checkboxes aren't present, not just one of them.

Comment: Also, make sure you avoid spaces between the options.