# Laravel 5 Validations

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I want to validate my form fields using laravel 5.

Form field 1 ->  User ID :

Form Field 2 ->  Other Name :

Either of the form field is required. 
i mean if user id is present other name should be blank and if other name is present `user_id` should be blank.

I am trying to use:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
                            [
                        'user_id ' => $user_id,
                        'user_name' => $user_name
                            ], [
                        'user_id' => 'required_without:user_name',
                        'user_name' => 'required_without:user_id'
            ]);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return Utility::validation_err($validator);
            }
```

While updating record even if user id is present it gives me error user id is required when other name is not present. also if i am filling out both it accepts both. It should accept one of both fields.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this one [same type of question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635678/laravel-validation-required-only-and-only-one-field)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own validation rule, for exmaple "only_one_id_name_required". It should be applied to both of fields. Next put extend Validator in App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
Validator::extendImplicit('only_one_id_name_required', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return (request()->has('user_id') xor request()->has('user_name'));
});
```

Use extendImplicit() instead of extend() to cover empty fields request.