# How to do a validation conditional in this case with Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have two fields. `author_id` and `teacher_id`. I would like one or the other to be required BUT if both are filled, it displays an error saying "there can be only one".

Is it possible to do this with validation rules in Laravel? I do not understand the documentation. Perhaps an example will be more meaningful (and an explanation)

Answer (score 2):

Your should use `required_without:foo,bar,...`   see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-without)

**example**

```
'author_id' => 'required_without:teacher_id',
'teacher_id' => 'required_without:author_id',
```

Comment: Sorry, but I test your solution. It works but if I fill both fields, it works also when I do not want to be able to fill all the fields. Only one or the other but not both.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I have a field teacher_id and a field author_id (actually, they are both authors, but with different information). I only want one author per article (and therefore, a teacher_id OR an author_id). So if I fill both in my administration, I want it to make a mistake (you can only choose one, not both).

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635678/laravel-validation-required-only-and-only-one-field its a bit of a hack but works as intended

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes is better to use custom after validation hook, for example:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validator(): \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{
    $validator = Validator::make($this->all(), [
        'file' => 'required_without:url|file',
        'url'  => 'required_without:file|url'
    ]);

    if ($this->has('url') && $this->has('file')) {
        $validator->after(function (\Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator) {
            $validator->errors()->add('url', 'error message');
        });
    }

    return $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are mention 2 different ways to do conditional validation
e.g. Login functionality need **fcmToken** required if **deviceType** is "android"

1. in Controller

> public function login(Request $request){
>     // Validate fcmToken required if deviceType exist and android
>
> if($request->has('deviceType')  && $request['deviceType'] == "android")
>       {
>          $request->validate([
>            'fcmToken' => 'required',
>            );
>          } 
>       }

2. In Request Extended Class

> use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
>       class LoginRequest extends FormRequest {
>           public function authorize()
>           {
>               return true;
>           }
>
> ```
>     public function rules()
>     {
>         return [
>             'email'    => 'required|string',
>             'password' => 'required',
>             'fcmToken'    => 'string',
>             'deviceType' => 'required|string'
>         ];
>     } }
> ```